# LeetCode: error trying to run with my own editor

Tags: python

I am working on Leetcode problem 108. Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree (https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/). Solution below works fine in Leetcode but when I try to run in VScode, error saying "NameError: name 'TreeNode' is not defined" occur.

```
from typing import List, Optional

nums = [-10,-3,0,5,9]


class solution:
    def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if not nums:
            return None
   
    
        mid_val=len(nums)//2 # Taking the floor value
    
        root= TreeNode(nums[mid_val])
    
    
        root.left=self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[:mid_val])
        root.right=self.sortedArrayToBST(nums[mid_val+1:])
    
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sol = solution()
    sol.sortedArrayToBST(nums)
```

Error is as below.
[image: Error saying 'TreeNode' is not defined.]

I want to code in my own editor but I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: Where is ```TreeNode``` defined/imported from?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: `TreeNode` is not defined or imported in Leetcode too

Comment: @David98  It is probably defined in leet code...  It is the part at the top in comments